# DelegatingHandler Request Origin

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have one DelegatingHandler to verify an ApiKey included in the Request Header:

```
public class ApiKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!ApiKey.VerifyRequest(request))
        {
            var response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid Api Key");
            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(response);
            return tsc.Task;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Now I want to extend it to check the origin of the request, because this APIKey is only required for external requests (CORS has not be required yet).
External is defined by Domain and its exclusively Server to Server.

I found the Is_Local Property but this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now going with the IP Address:
`((dynamic)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;`

Comment: It is the solution for my Problem. So it should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be needing an IP of the caller, [WebApiContrib](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs) has a good extension method that works on both self host and web host:

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
    private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
    private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";

    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
        {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        }

        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
        {
            dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
            if (remoteEndpoint != null)
            {
                return remoteEndpoint.Address;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```